# Find all previous LIs in group of ULs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to select all previous LIs from the selected li in the following code. I'm guessing it is some combination of .closest() and .prev() or .prevAll()-- but getting stuck having it select everything from multiple parents. Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="thumbsContainer">
  <div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li class="selected">thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your code, because from your description it would be as simple as: `$("li.selected").prevAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all previous `li` elements as,

```js
const getPreviousListItems = (callback) => {
  const previousListItems = [];

  $('li').each((index, elem) => {
    if(!$(elem).hasClass('selected')){
      previousListItems.push(elem);
    }
    else{
      return callback(previousListItems);
    }
  });
};


getPreviousListItems((previousListItems) => {
  console.log(previousListItems);
  $(previousListItems).each((index, elem) => {
    $(elem).css( 'background-color', '#BBDEFB' );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbsContainer">
  <div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li class="selected">thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

`previousListItems` consist if `li` elements before the selected one.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two sets of `li`'s preceeding each li, one resides within the same parent as the target `li` and the others within other parents but precceds the target `li`.

Created and merged two arrays one for the `li`s 'on the same level and the other for `li`'s within different parents.

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  var prevLi1 = $(this).closest(".categoryContainer").prevAll(".categoryContainer").find("li");
  var prevLi2 = $(this).prevAll("li");
  var allPrevLis = $.merge(prevLi1, prevLi2);
  //To Display the prev lis
  allPrevLis.each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red')
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbsContainer">
  <div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li class="selected">thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful! That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `prevAll()` of your selected element:

```js
$(".selected").prevAll().css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li class="selected">thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
      <li>thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you-- prevAll() seems to only affect LIs within the same parent UL. I am looking to grab all previous LIs, even from other parent ULs.